# Can a single answer receive multiple bounties?

Tags: support, bounties

I know already that multiple bounties can be started on the same question (albeit not concurrently); but, can multiple bounties be awarded to the same *answer*?

For example: can I start a bounty against a question in order to reward an answer that has *already* received a previous bounty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, an answer can receive multiple bounties. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/2619912), for example, got 10 bounties awarded.

Answer (score 3):

From the [central bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> Any answer to the question, **even an existing answer that has already been awarded one or more bounties**, is eligible to be manually awarded the bounty.

Emphasis mine. It doesn't matter if an answer already received a bounty before, you can always award it another bounty.

Comment: I mustn't have looked hard enough!